# How can I get when the last time that consumer commit an offset?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to search when that a consumer group last commit an offset. I'm not trying to know the position of the offset, but rather the time that the consumer group last commit the offset.

I've tried running:

`bin/windows/kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group consumer-group --describe --topic com.gdn.test`

But all this does is showing me the group, current offset, partition, etc like I show in the image below: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timestamp information isn't stored with group offsets, it's only part of the topic segment files.

For example, to find the time of the record at the committed offset, that can be found using a consumer and seeking to the committed offset, polling that one record, then looking at the record timestamp.

You can similarly do this for the __consumer_offsets topic, and searching for the group name for when any group was produced to this topic (i.e. when offsets were committed)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i use a Kafka UI tool called [Kafka tool](https://www.kafkatool.com/).

In this tool, you can check the consumers. For each consumer, you can find the data returned by the `kafka-consumer-groups.bat` command and the **last commit** date as shown in the screen shot below:
[image: Consumer details]
FYI, i tried to understand how the **last commit** date it retrieved but unfortunately this tool is not open source. I guess it is done like how [@OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77453582/6615961) described.